# WKInterfaceTable not creating rows

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

I'm trying to build a simple WatchKit app with a Table. Each row has a Label. Here's my TableRowController class:

```
import WatchKit

class TaskTableRowController: NSObject {

    @IBOutlet var taskName: WKInterfaceLabel!
}
```

In my InterfaceController, I add a row to my Table and try to set the Label's text. However, taskList.rowController(at: 0) does not find a row, so the Label is unmodified.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet var taskList: WKInterfaceTable!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
        taskList.setNumberOfRows(1, withRowType: "TaskRow")
        if let x = taskList.rowController(at: 0) as? TaskTableRowController
        {
            x.taskName.setText("Hello World")
        }
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```

Here's some screens from Interface Builder and the output:
[image: Interface Builder]
[image: Watch Simulator]

Comment: Look at this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/selectable-table-watchkit/

Comment: @csstudent Please check below answer...

Comment: are you check below code It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Following code, It works for me :

```
    taskList.setNumberOfRows(10, withRowType: "TaskRow")

    for index in 0..<taskList.numberOfRows {
        if let controller = taskList.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? TaskTableRowController {
            controller.taskName.setText("Hello World")
        }
    }
```

I have seen the screen shots but pl. Cross check & Make sure below points :

- `WKInterfaceLabel`**(taskName)** has an `IBOutlet` in your
  `TaskTableRowController`.
- `TaskTableRowController` identifier is set
  to 'TaskRow'.
- `WKInterfaceTable`**(taskList)** has an IBOutlet.
- The custom class for your row 'TaskTableRowController' is set.

Hope it helps you !!!

Do let me know if you have any query.